# Why Integers are type casted to Byte in EF Core DB First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

EF Core Scaffold Command was executed against SQL. Here is generated Entity Type Configuration Code:

```
    builder.HasIndex(e => new { e.Type, e.Code }, "IDX_CODES_TYPE_CODE")
        .HasFillFactor(**(byte)**90);
```

However it can be safely written as:

```
    builder.HasIndex(e => new { e.Type, e.Code }, "IDX_CODES_TYPE_CODE")
        .**HasFillFactor(**90**);**
```

Is this generator error?

I do see typeacsting works, by why does Microsoft generate this at first place?

```
void Main()
{
    int x = (byte)10;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is an error?

Comment: Given that only values between 0 and 100 are valid for a fill factor, the fact that `HasFillFactor` accepts an `int` might be considered worse than what's happening here.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, if there is an overload to accept int parameter in HasFillFactor why typecast?

Comment: @Abhijeet you need to go through the source code but I would guess it it due to the fill factor limits somewhere along the lines corresponding type was used. Either in db it is stored as `tinyint` (which is mapped to byte) or inside the generator itself it is stored in bytes.